# Why won't vendors restock?

Tags: fallout-4

Vendors in my current game of Fallout 4 wont restock their items. I've been waiting for weeks for a mini nuke to be restocked.

Why don't they restock? Would it have anything to do with the mods I have installed?

Comment: Hi fell2162 - welcome to Arqade! We can't really tell you if a mod would affect this if you don't list which mods you have installed...

Answer (score -1):

If it's like skyrim I'd say wait 48 hours or do the old quick save kill and reload trick.

Hope I helped!